# Qt C++ MainWindow::setMenuWidget not working

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to add a custom widget with the help of MainWindow::setMenuWidget.
But this doesnt work properly.
Here is the code:
Piece of MainWindow constructor:

```
MyMenuBar *menu = new MyMenuBar();

connect(menu,SIGNAL(Close_Window()),this,SLOT(close()));
connect(menu,SIGNAL(Minimized_Window()),this,SLOT(hide()));

menu->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

this->setMenuWidget(menu);
menu->show();
```

So, it compiles successfully, starts but my widget is not appears.
I've checked

```
this->menuWidget();
```

and it's not null.

If I've changing code like this

```
MyMenuBar *menu = new MyMenuBar();

connect(menu,SIGNAL(Close_Window()),this,SLOT(close()));
connect(menu,SIGNAL(Minimized_Window()),this,SLOT(hide()));

menu->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

//this->setMenuWidget(menu);
menu->show();
```

Then my widget shows properly but it behaves like a separate window.

Can someone help me with that problem? Thanks.

Comment: Specified menu parent.
MyMenuBar *menu = new MyMenuBar(this);

Answer (score 0):

@Ankur thanks dude.
It works, but when I'm setting the parent, I dont need to use

```
this->setMenuWidget(menu)
```

So, the final code looks like:

```
MyMenuBar *menu = new MyMenuBar(this);

connect(menu,SIGNAL(Close_Window()),this,SLOT(close()));
connect(menu,SIGNAL(Minimized_Window()),this,SLOT(hide()));

menu->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
menu->show();
```